# Странный результат при делении больших чисел с использованием библиотеки MPIR

Tags: c++

Всем привет, столкнулся с тем что при использовании библиотеки MPIR (версия mpir-2.7.2 + VS 2015) при делении больших чисел получаю в результате не то что ожидал, при этом некоторые операции проходят нормально.

Код программы:

```
#include <mpirxx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

#define INPUT_FILE "C:\\in.txt"

using namespace std;
int main()
{


    FILE* fi = NULL;
    FILE* fo = NULL;
    char* inbuffer = NULL;

    do
    {
        fi = fopen(INPUT_FILE, "r");
        if (fi == NULL)
        {
            printf("cannot open file %s for read\n", INPUT_FILE);
            break;
        }

        fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_END);
        long lSize = ftell(fi);
        rewind(fi);


        char* inbuffer = new char[lSize + 1];
        memset(inbuffer, 0, lSize + 1);


        // copy the file into the buffer:

        size_t rc = fread(inbuffer, 1, lSize, fi);
        if (rc != lSize)
        {
            printf("cannot read all file. size:%d, read size:%d\n", lSize, rc);
            break;
        }

        char pibuf[] =
            "999999";
        mpf_t a, b, c;
        mpf_init2(a, 8 * sizeof(inbuffer));
        mpf_init2(b, 8 * sizeof(pibuf));
        mpf_init2(c, 8 * sizeof(inbuffer));
        //mpf_set_d(a, 22222222.222222);
        mpf_set_str(a, inbuffer, 10);
        mpf_set_str(b, pibuf, 10);
        mp_exp_t exp;
        mpf_div(c, a, b);
        printf("A:%s\n\n\nB:%s\n\nC:%s\n",
            mpf_get_str(NULL, &exp, 10, 0, a),
            mpf_get_str(NULL, &exp, 10, 0, b),
            mpf_get_str(NULL, &exp, 10, 0, c));
        mpf_clear(a);
        mpf_clear(b);
        mpf_clear(c);
    }

    while (false);
    if (fi != NULL)
    {
        fclose(fi);
    }





    getchar();




    if (inbuffer != NULL)
    {
        delete[] inbuffer;
    }



}
```

Что не так:
[image: не ясно где целая часть]
[image: не верно воспринимает значение делителя]

Comment: Верно считает если делитель 1, если делитель 9999999 то воспринимает его верно, в отличии от 100000000 но не верно считает.

Answer (score 2):

Уберите запятую из ответа, полученного в win-калькуляторе. Получите в точности то, что хотели. Вы же не учитываете значение `exp`, которое показывает положение запятой.

Насколько я знаю, mpf хранит число в виде мантиссы и экспоненты, в формате с плавающей запятой. Вы вывели именно мантиссу, а по уму нужно после неё вывести символ `e` и затем экспоненту. Что-то вроде `7644875636363636e-10`.

Comment: Ещё рекомендую изучить функцию `gmp_fprintf`, она позволяет гораздо больше всяких способов вывода, чем вы можете сделать через преобразование в строку.

Comment: мне как раз и нужно число без exp, что бы получить точное значение результата деления. Реально ли это сделать?

Comment: Я же сказал, изучите `gmp_fprintf`, там должна быть такая возможность. Эта функция, не смотря на название, тоже есть в MPIR.

Comment: Благодарю, будем изучать.